# How to delete buttons or labels from a tkinter window in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was recently working on a simple game in python 3 which involves tkinter. I encountered a significant problem. I can not figure out how to delete a label or button from a tkinter window in Python 3.5.2. If you know how please answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you use [`pack`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) to add the widget to the window, then you can use [`pack_forget`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_forget-method) to remove it from the window. To add it back again, call `pack` again. If you want to permanently get rid of the widget, then use `destroy` (You won't be able to get it back).

Answer (score 1):

For example here is a label:

```
widgetname = tk.Label(text = "Hello World").pack()
```

You can use the `destroy()` property to permanently remove it.  This cannot be retrieved and the widget would need to be defined again.

```
widgetname.destroy()
```

A complete example can be found [here](http://www.pythonlake.com/tkinterbuttondestroy)

Or you can use `pack_forget()` to hide the element.  You just need to use `pack()` or `grid()` again to show it again

```
widgetname.pack_forget()
```

[See this page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_forget-method)